# how to optimize multiple sub-queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get some user statistics from mysql. Something like:

- 10% users bought pepsi
- 20% are woman
- 40% are on USA

The first step is get a list of all users had bought something from Pepsi manufacturer.

This query is working well in less then 1 second and returns a list of user ids.

```
SELECT DISTINCT idUser FROM checkout_item INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM product WHERE manufacturer = "pepsi"
) AS chkItem ON chkItem.id = checkout_item.idProduct
```

Now I use this list to get information. Just added a query above:

```
SELECT
  name, gender
FROM users INNER JOIN(

  SELECT DISTINCT idUser FROM checkout_item INNER JOIN (   //
    SELECT id FROM product WHERE manufacturer = "pepsi"    // same query above
  ) AS chkItem ON chkItem.id = checkout_item.idProduct     //

) AS usr ON usr.idUser = users.id
```

This query is working, but it takes 23 seconds. Is there any way to optimize this?

Maybe using WHEREs, JOINs, or changing mysql RAM configs?

Comment: Does your tables indexed?

Comment: thanks @lolka_bolka, I've created indexes on NAME and GENDER fields and it now takes 2 seconds.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that indexes on name and gender would help since they're not included in any of the filtering parameters.  Is the query that's changed different to the query you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite of your first query. Maybe you can figure out the rest.

```
SELECT DISTINCT idUser 
           FROM checkout_item i
           JOIN product p 
             ON p.id = i.idproduct
          WHERE p.manufacturer = 'pepsi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Select Name, gender
from checkout_item c INNER JOIN (Select Id from product WHERE manufacturer = "pepsi") p ON p.id = C.idProduct
INNER JOIN users u ON C.idUser = u.Id

Also think of putting an index on checkout_item field idProduct

Answer (score 0):

The below should give you the total number of idUsers, and the total number of idUsers who are women (obviously I don't know what you use as a flag for gender, so I've just used 'f').

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT idUser) AS Total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN gender = 'f' then idUser else null end) AS women
FROM    checkout_item ci
    inner join product p
        on p.id=ci.idProduct
WHERE   p.manufacturer = 'pepsi'
```

From there it should be basic maths to get the figures you need.

ordinarily I wouldn't recommend using 'DISTINCT', however not knowing much about your data it's the quick and dirty way to make something that works.

Hope that helps!